# Dynamically adding a file to a product archive built by Tycho

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

Adding a file to a product distribution archive built with Maven/Tycho is possible: 
[see this link](http://vzurczak.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/removing-root-files-in-a-rcp-built-with-tycho/)

But how can I add a dynamically chosen file to my archive? For example this could be a data file.

Comment: What do you mean with "not always in the same place"? How does the linked article relate to your question? Please make sure that you provide enough detail to give people a chance to understand what you are asking. Right now this is not the case.

Comment: Edit done. Better for you?

Comment: It's getting better... With "archive" you refer to a product distribution archive (i.e. a zip/tar with an Eclipse installation), right? Is your dynamic mechanism able to set a property in the Maven model?

Comment: :). Right, I refer to a product distribution archive. If I understood your question, the file is not important during the Maven process, it is "just" important to run the application.

Comment: What is "dynamic" about the file to be added? E.g. does the file content vary between builds? Or the file name?

Comment: Yes, the file version will change and so it will be moved.

Comment: I'm gonna try something,(use the maven lifecycle to launch a java class which will include the file ). but if you find something better, go on :)

Comment: Sorry, took me a while to write the answer. Does this solve your problem? (If the answer is yes, you should accept the answer by selecting the check-mark next to the question.) Is it better than what you had found yourself? (If solution was also good, you could write it as another answer.)

Comment: Sorry, I was working on some other stuff. The file I want to add to my product archive, is a license so I need Maven or Tycho to select this file among others by its date. For example, I would like to add only the last one. Moreover, I need my license file to be placed elsewhere than in target/rootfiles.

Comment: "Add goals in the pom.xml of the feature build so that the file(s) you want to have included in the distribution archive are copied/added to the target/rootfiles folder during the build." If you don't know how to do this, ask a new question.

Comment: "When the feature with the root files configuration is added to the product, the files you have put into target/rootfiles will end up in the product distribution archive." so e.g. a file copied to `target/rootfiles/foo/bar.txt` will end up as `foo/bar.txt` in the product.

Comment: I used the process you described in your answer, but here it is different. I don"t want to choose the file manually (or add it in the rootfiles). I would like to know if a file among others can be choosen by its date (most recent one) and then be added to the archive. 
The important fact is : How to pick a specific file and not all the files ? ( because if I add x files in the target folder, they'll all be  used, arent they?)

Comment: "How to pick a specific file and not all the files?" You'll not get any other answer from me on this question but "find a Maven goal which picks the files you wants and copies them to `target/rootfiles`" The rest is explained in my answer.

Comment: Seems like I have difficulties to explain my issue.

Comment: So if I manage to solve it by myself, I'll comeback to post the answer. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I created a mojo to add the files. The difficulty was that the files to add depended on the product.

Answer (score 5):

The article you linked deals with removing files from a product distribution archive, which can be quite challenging. **Adding files to a distribution archive is a lot simpler**, and doesn't require any of the low-level p2 hacking described in the article.

In order to add a file to a product distribution archive, include add it as as root files to one of the features included in your product:

1. In the `build.properties` of the feature build, add a line `root=file:target/rootfiles/**`
2. Add goals in the pom.xml of the feature build so that the file(s) you want to have included in the distribution archive are copied/added to the `target/rootfiles` folder during the build. E.g. the [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/plugin-info.html) or the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/plugin-info.html) could do this.

When the feature with the root files configuration is added to the product, the files you have put into `target/rootfiles` will end up in the product distribution archive.

In case you have problems with this, you also may have a look at [this example project](http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho-demo.git/tree/itp04-rcp).

Comment: the example seems to take the files directly from rootfiles/ without copying and any other maven plugins.
will this work?

Comment: @oers Sure, you can of course just as well include "static" files which are part of the sources, e.g. directly from `rootfiles`.

Comment: Is there a way to chmod the file when it's copied into the distribuiton archive file? I'm putting a shell script in my app, and I don't want the user to have to manually run chmod. I tried metadata customizaziton using a p2.inf file in the feature, but I can't get it to work as I do with files that remain inside a certain installable unit

Comment: The answer to my question above is in the Example Project linked in the answer (example-feature). Here's a link with some explanation of the example, showing how to set permissions near the bottom of the article: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Demo_Projects/RCP_Application.

Comment: My question is silimar to @oers . Is it possible the `rootfiles` are not static but they come during maven build ?